# I want to send the textbox value to the controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the a textbox in my view like this

```
< input type="text" id="Quant" value="@item.Quantity"/>
```

i want to send the value of this textbox to the action method when the text box value is changed.

my action method is like this

```
public ActionResult Quant(int id)
{
    int index = isExisting(id);
    List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
    cart[index].Quantity= id;
    Session["cart"] = cart;
    return View("Cart");
}
```

i want the textbox value to be sent to parameter id of the actionresult Quant.
whether we can use any javascript or jquery for this.
plz help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why use javascript? Why not just submit a form (you need to give the input a name attribute `name="id"`)

Comment: javascript does not require page update. it is very simple and makes you site interactive.

Answer (score 2):

Well first you need to figure out when you want to send the text value to the controller. When the textbox changes or on keyup of the textbox or similar. I would probably put this in the textbox changing which you can do using on input. Then you could run some ajax code as follows:

```
$('#Quant').on("input propertychange paste", function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/Quant',
    data: { 'id' : $('#Quant').val() },
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
        alert('success !');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Just modify your code

**First Input Box:**

```
<input type="text" id="Quant" name ="Quant" value="@item.Quantity"/>
```

**Second Correct Action Method:**

```
public ActionResult Quant(String Quant)
{
    int _Quant = Convert.ToInt16(Quant);
    int index = isExisting(id);
    List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
    cart[index].Quantity= id;
    Session["cart"] = cart;
    return View("Cart");
}
```

Comment: he says the value has to be posted when the text box value is changed. so this isn,t enough